# change calculated column into measure in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I want to change calculated column into measure so that I can use slicers to change the measure in Power BI.

I want to compare the table1's value and table1's deductible with the table2's threshold (next row) and sum up the table1's value.

Sample Data:

```
Table1
Value    Deductible
51000    45000      
56000    57000
```

```
Table2
Threshold    The Result to calculate
50000        51000         
55000        107000    
60000
```

The output is the second column in Table2.

The code for the calculated column is:

```
value_below_threshold = 
VAR CurThreshold = table2[Threshold]
VAR NextThreshold = table2[Threshold] + 5000
VAR __RelevantRowsTable2 =
    FILTER (
        'table1',
         'table1'[value] < NextThreshold
            && 'table1'[Deductible] < NextThreshold
    )
VAR __RelevantRowsTable3 = 
    FILTER (table2,
        contains(
        'table2',
        table2[Threshold],
        NextThreshold)
    )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( sum(table1[value]), __RelevantRowsTable2, __RelevantRowsTable3  )
```

But I don't know how to change this calculated column into measure.
Does anyone can help me for this problem?
Thank you very much!

Comment: Can you show your sample data with your expected output?

Comment: I have updated the sample data and expected output. Thanks!!